# Cant retrieve greek characters from mysql database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, collation

- currently on Wamp 2.20
- MySQL version : 5.5.20
- PHP version   : 5.3.10
- table collation : utf8-bin
- `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

while i can see the data saved in the MySQL table are the Greek characters, when i try to echo them from PHP, they turn into "?" question marks.

Comment: View your html source to see what is being produced.  Likely you will need to encode the characters before the browser will render them appropriately.

Comment: You can also check the encoding of your php files.

Comment: check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806319/php-mysql-greek-letters-showing-like-marks) Its the same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your client connection is set for UTF8. Examples:

**SQL**

```
SET NAMES UTF8;
```

**PHP MySQLi**

```
mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
```

**PHP PDO**

```
$handle = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname",
  'username', 'password', 
  array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
));
```

PHP mysql (deprecated - **do not use**)

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to encode your special characters before echo'ing your data.

```
echo htmlentities($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that your file are saved using `ANSI as UTF-8` aka `UTF-8 without BOM`. You can do it using NotePad++ : http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/document-properties/encoding

Also, when working with UTF-8 (Unicode) please remember :

- All files must be saved using UTF-8 encoding ;
- MySQL tables must be in UTF-8 ;
- Fields in MySQL must be UTF-8 ;
- PHP must be set to use UTF-8 ;
- Everything has to be UTF-8 encoded.