# PHP MySQL Greek letters showing like ???? marks

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a table with some text and text is greek letters, when i use sql tool and select the data from this table is showing correctly
[image: Image for SQL Query Results]

But when i show this my site frontend using mysql_fetch array and when echo it shows as below
[image]

Anyone know how to fix this error
thank you.

Comment: what the character encoding for the db, db connection, web page ? in short they should be identical

Comment: utf8_general_ci is the character encoding

Comment: nope mate, other  texts are showing correctly
http://tsiopelakos.dev-centiva.com/index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=2&Itemid=322&txtTitle=&txtIsbn=&txtIsbn13=&txtAuthor=&txtEditor=&txtDfrom=&txtDto=&txtType=&txtPricefrom=&txtPriceto=

Comment: Read: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: but is it the encoding on all three things i pointed to?

Comment: mysql_set_charset('utf8');
it is working, thank for help @deceze and dagon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try the following:

after you connect to the mysql, do this query to make sure that you are using UTF8:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

make sure that in HTML (head) you are using the right encoding, try:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

if this does not help, try different encoding, like ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
```

After you connect to DB.

Comment: Nice Marios. Simple as that. It is actually a different way to change the encoding if you are using mysqli.

Answer (score 6):

Leaving this here for those who come to this site via Google because they have the same issue but use PDO instead (like me) - you should be fine with:

```
$dns = "mysqli:host=localhost;dbname=db_name";
$pdo = new PDO($dns, 'db_user', 'db_pass',
        array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
$pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasted many hours till i figured this out.

**Intro:**
Greek characters were appearing wrong in mysql. I applied **qxxx** answer in PHP and worked fine.
Then I had to migrate everything to a new host, and then the problem reappeared.

**What was wrong?**

The MySQL's schema charset was set to latin. The stored procedures had inherited MySQL's schema charset for their parameters.

**So what I did:**

1. Dropped MySQL procedures/functions (make sure you backup your code)
2. Changed default charset of MySQL (using MySQL Workbench, right click on your database name-has a db icon..)
3. re-created the MySQL procedures/functions

Also, I left intact the **qxxx** 's fix!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to drop tables or anything.
Use MySQL Workbench and go to each table. Change the Collation to utf8 - default collation or utf8 - general ci.
Then do the same for each column with type Varchar - it is found at the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while implementing Greek Characters. The solutions like mysql_`query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");` did not work for me. After Googling, I found that, the character set for the database collation should be made `greek_general_ci` along with the field where data would be stored like categoryname etc. This solved my problem.