# Cannot properly insert greek characters in mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, character-encoding, http-headers

Our mysql database shows `Î Î¿Î»Ï Î³Î»Ï…ÎºÏŒÏ` in place of greek characters while sending data from an emulator to a mysql database. Other characters are left ok.

screenshot from phpMyAdmin:

[image: data]

UPDATE:

After using

@Félix Gagnon-Grenier answer in my code it gives me this:

[image: Database]

Sql for table creation

```
CREATE TABLE `cart` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `product_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `product_price` double(3,2) NOT NULL,
 `product_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `preferation1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `preferation2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `preferation3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `preferation4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `magazi_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `servitoros_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

[image]

php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    mb_http_input("utf-8");
    try {
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'username', 'password');
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' ");
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }

    $productName = $_POST['productName'];
    $productPrice=$_POST['productPrice'];
    $productImage = $_POST['productImage'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $sugar = $_POST['sugar'];
    $milk = $_POST['milk'];
    $flavor=$_POST['flavor'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $magazi = $_POST['magazi_id'];
    $servitoros = $_POST['servitoros_id'];

    $handler->query("INSERT INTO cart(id, product_name, product_price, product_image, quantity, preferation1, preferation2, preferation3, preferation4, magazi_id, servitoros_id) VALUES('', '$productName','$productPrice','$productImage', '$quantity', '$sugar', '$milk', '$flavor', '$comment', '$magazi', '$servitoros')");
    die();
?>
```

Java

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("productName", productName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("productPrice", String.valueOf(price)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("productImage", image));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quantity", String.valueOf(quantityNumberFinal)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sugar", sugarPreference));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("milk", milkPreference));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("flavor", flavorPreference));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", comment));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("magazi_id", String.valueOf(2)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("servitoros_id", String.valueOf(13)));
            try
            {
                HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParams, "UTF-8");
                httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
                httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: What is your Character Set in your Table?

Comment: Use ISO-8859-1 for your character set.

Comment: go through this [Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-charsets.html), it may help you

Comment: @VishalRathod of course not. ISO-8859-1 does not support greek.

Comment: Are you greek texts saved as they should in DB? or the DB rows also says ?????????
Use iso-8859-8 for your charset. Take a look 
[http://a4esl.org/c/charset.html](http://a4esl.org/c/charset.html)

Comment: execute $handler->query('set names UTF-8') before executing your real query. This might solve the problem.

Comment: This might help : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806319/php-mysql-greek-letters-showing-like-marks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806319/php-mysql-greek-letters-showing-like-marks)

Comment: nope does not work either

Comment: what are you doing in the java code to set utf-8 encoding? is it not transfering data?

Comment: it transfers all the data to db except that the greek characters are in ???????

Comment: Well, from your update it looks like the characters are encoded twice. You may be doing a bit too much with all the settings for utf-8 at the top of your script. I would remove them all (except them for the database), test, then add them one by one, starting from the header, testing between each.

Comment: You can try setting the default character set in mysql`mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");`

Comment: I don't think your issue comes from the database. I recommend you to check the encoding on Java side. Maybe it could be useful also testing the database without the application.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored -- Look for Mojibake and for Question Marks

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is related to your charset-encoding. It's important that your *entire* code has the same charset to avoid issues where characters displays incorrectly.

There are quite a few settings that needs to be properly defined and I'd strongly recommend UTF-8, as this has most letters you would need (Scandinavian, Greek, Arabic, Russian, etc.).

Here's a little list of things that has to be set to a specific charset.

**Headers**

- Setting the charset in both HTML and PHP headers to UTF-8

  - PHP:

    ```
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    ```

    (PHP headers has to be placed before *any* output (echo, whitespace,
    HTML)!)
  - HTML:

    ```
    <meta charset=utf-8" />
    ```

    (HTML-headers are placed within the `<head>` / `</head>` tag)

**Connection**

- You also need to specify the charset in the *connection itself*. For your PDO example, it's done like this

  ```
  $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET CHARACTER SET UTF8"));
  ```

  Note the `charset=utf8`-attribute. Other MySQL-APIs have different ways of doing this should you use something else in the future.

**Database**

- Your *database* and its tables has to be set to UTF-8. Note that charset is *not* the same as collation. I see you already set your collation to UTF-8, so that's good, but do the same for the entire database and all tables.

  You can do that by running the queries below once for each database and tables (for example in phpMyAdmin)

  ```
  ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; 
  ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
  ```

  Note that any data already stored in the database will not automatically have their broken charset fixed. So its important you do this before inserting data, or that you re-insert it after setting the charset.

**php.ini specification**

- In your `php.ini` file, you should specify the default charset for your platform, like this

  ```
  default_charset = "utf-8";
  ```

**File-encoding**

- It's also important that the `.php` file itself is UTF-8 encoded. If you're using Notepad++ to write your code, this can be done in the "Format" drop-down on the taskbar.

**Emojis**

- In MySQL (both in the table, database and connection-object), you will need to specify the `utf8mb4` charset, as opposed to regular `utf8`, if you wish to work with emojis.

I don't know much about Java, but if you can set attributes to UTF-8 there as well, do it. In essence, everything that can be set to a specific charset should be set to the same.

Should you follow all of the pointers above, chances are your problem will be solved. If not, you can take a look at this StackOverflow post: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Comment: i have done everything that you suggest but still the same

Comment: I see you updated your code after my post, but you did not include `charset=utf8` in your connection-object. Is that just left out of the code you updated, or do you actually have it in your *actual* code? @KostasDrakonakis

Comment: i left it out but whether is in or out it gives me the same result

Comment: Never the less, it *should* be in there. It's important that the connection has the charset set to UTF-8. However, if you `echo $sugar;` before you insert it, is it in the proper format?

Answer (score 1):

An excellent introduction about using UTF8 with PHP and Mysql can be found in [this blog](http://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql). The main points are:

1. Set the database tables to UTF8
2. In your php.ini set `default_charset = "utf-8";`
3. After the connection is established you may have to run the following command/query: `set names UTF-8;`

I guess you are missing point 3.

In your PHP script, you should do something like this (untested):

```
$handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 
  'username', 
  'password',
  array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 
    'SET NAMES utf8;SET CHARACTER SET UTF8;'));
```

Comment: Maybe it is just the logging console that is set to the wrong charset? Did you look in the database via another way (console or phpMyAdmin or something)

Comment: And? Do the values contain Greek characters in the DB? So is the problem related to inserting or retrieving, or both?

Comment: preferation1 and preferation2 are the greek data i want to insert

Comment: i wonder does it have to do anything if it is InnoDB or MyISAM?

Answer (score 1):

Use database varchar field as utf8_general_ci.

Answer (score 1):

Your whole php/mysql setup seems to be encoded with utf-8, but the java code isn't, starting from there:

```
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

First, the [`DefaultHttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) class seems to be deprecated. However, docs say that

> This class sets up the following parameters if not explicitly set:
>
> - ContentCharset: HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET

The http default charset is `ISO-8859-1` according to the [java constant field values](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/constant-values.html)

The [`HttpPost`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) itself does not appear to mingle with character sets.

But the [`UrlEncodedFormEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html) does. Also from the docs:

```
UrlEncodedFormEntity(Iterable parameters)
Constructs a new UrlEncodedFormEntity with the list of parameters with the default encoding of HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET
```

Since `ISO-8859-1` can't keep greek characters, passing them through those instances will modify them, hence breaking the characters in your php code.

**All of this code seems to be deprecated**, but change java to output utf-8 encoded characters:

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParams ,"UTF-8");
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));
```

**and remove redundancy in your php:**

```
ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_input("utf-8");
```

Header will overwrite the ini_set, so you can remove it, and the http input is already in utf8 (since we just transformed it in java), so you can remove it too:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Comment: first of all DefaultHttpClient works fine since i have imported legacy library. now ISO-8859-1 does not support greek characters

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a php script to insert data into data base then first use `utf8_encode` function on data to be inserted and then use `utf8_decode` on the same data and then perform the database insertion operation.

Comment: Dont use any encode/decode functions.  When properly configured conversions are automatic.