# Mathematical symbol not supported in php

Tags: php

I have a some text saved in a MySql database that contains a mathematical symbol. When I read this from php code it become something like this `α=?` and `β=?`

Text in database:

```
<p>A round balloon of radius r subtends an angle α at the eye of the observer, while the angle of elevation of the centre is β. The height of the centre of balloon is </p>
```

Text read from php:

```
<p>A round balloon of radius r subtends an angle ? at the eye of the observer, while the angle of elevation of the centre is ?. The height of the centre of balloon is </p>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried `htmlentities()` ? before saving? also, does your database field support utf8 characters(in sql server you would need nvarchar instead of varchar)

Comment: what you tried update here

Answer (score 1):

Most likely is that your database and php don't share the same character set. You should set all of your systems to (for instance) UTF-8 so that characters may be shared between systems.

In your html/php page:

```
<meta charset=utf-8" />
```

In your database you should also ensure the charset is set to UTF-8

There is a detailed example here in this answer to someone else's query. It wasn't picked as the answer but the information is very clear:

[Cannot properly insert greek characters in mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782413/cannot-properly-insert-greek-characters-in-mysql-database)