# Everything after a Greek letter is empty in my database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, encoding, character-encoding

I'm encountering what I'm sure is an encoding error but I can't seem to find the weak link in my logic.  In particular, when trying to insert a Greek lambda into my database, the cell is blank after the lambda.

The process:

Before any html is printed, I'm doing:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Next, I'm connecting using PDO:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['dbname'] . ';charset=utf8';
 $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $config['username'], $config['password'], $options);
            $dbh->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
            $dbh->exec("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1");
```

When I do

> SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM my_table

I can see that the collation is utf8_general_ci.
When I do:

> echo mb_detect_encoding($data_to_be_entered);

I get UTF-8

When I echo out $data_to_be_entered into the console right before I insert it into the database, I see: (=23)

However, in my database, I just see ( as the entry.

Comment: You can have a look at [Cannot properly insert greek characters in mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782413/cannot-properly-insert-greek-characters-in-mysql-database)

Comment: See Truncation in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: @Atif - Your reference talks about Mojibake; the problem here is Truncation.  And it turns out not to be Greek.

Answer (score 0):

That lambda  is the Mathematical symbol.  It is encoded in UTF-8 as the *four* bytes hex `F09D9C86`.  Therefore, it needs MySQL `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, not utf8.

If you want the Greek lambda `λ`, that works fine with `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).  The hex for it is `CEBB`.

Comment: Why did you reopen the question? The [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/285587) says exactly the same.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - (1) Truncation and Mojibake are different issues with different causes.  (2) It was not a Greek letter that caused trouble, but a math symbol.  (3) This needed utf8mb4; the other needed other solutions.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - And...  I struggled for years with UTF-8 issues; it took a long time to realize that there were at least 5 different causes of the problems, at least 4 different visible symptoms, and at least 6 different ways to fix them.  Using the wrong fix (because of misdiagnosis, or because of assuming it is an exact dup) does the user a disservice.