# PHP functions inside query

Tags: php, mysql

I use the following query through php:

```
<?php 
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO order` SET custom_field = '" 
     . $this->db->escape(isset($data['custom_field']) ? json_encode($data['custom_field']) : '') 
     . "',  payment_company_id = '" . $firstvalue[1] 
     . "',  payment_tax_id = '" . $secondvaluein . ");
?>
```

The insertion in custom_field column is done normally and i need to use its value splitted to put it in payment_company_id and payment_tax_id columns.

Data saved in custom_field are like this:

```
{"1":"value of first custom field","2":"value of second custom field"}
```

I used the following code before my script:

```
<?php
    $myfinalfield = $this->db->escape(isset($data['custom_field']) ? json_encode($data['custom_field']) : '');
    $array = explode('","', $myfinalfield);
    $firstvalue = explode(':"', $array[0]);
    $secondvalue = explode(':"', $array[1]);
    $secondvaluein =  str_replace('"}','', $secondvalue[1]);
?>
```

in order to use $firstvalue[1] and $secondvaluein to the insert as you see to the first query above, but my columns are filled with nothing. Any ideas on this?

P.S. Also if i type greek characters then even in custom_field column even if its collation is utf8_general_ci i getn wrong encoding.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is `$myvar` when you try to `explode()` into `$array` ? It shouldn't be `$myfinalfield` actually ?

Comment: Perhaps you found my error! Let me check! ANy ideas about encoding i ask at end ?

Comment: If you'd print the query instead of querying? What would you get?

Comment: Not sure, you could check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11806319/1267304) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32782413/1267304).

Comment: I corrected the $myvar but still its not bringing results.

Comment: I have read those posts but i don't do any connection its an inner file and also other variables are being saved just fine in the table.

Comment: `json_encode` requires only a utf-8 data. Output the `json_last_error_msg()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are not checking for an error after running your query.

When I try to make sense of the query string you are generating, I get this:

```
INSERT INTO order` SET custom_field = 'something',  /* wrong! */
            payment_company_id = 'something',  payment_tax_id = 'something);
```

That isn't a valid query.  The following would be more valid. (Notice the extra backtick and the extra close-quote at the end of the query.)

```
INSERT INTO `order` SET custom_field = 'something',  
            payment_company_id = 'something',  payment_tax_id = 'something');
```

Your best bet for doing this kind of work is to use php to create strings containing your queries, then use the strings in calls to `query()`. That way when things don't work you can dump the query strings and inspect them.

Something like this, adapting your code.

```
$query =  "INSERT INTO `order` SET custom_field = '" 
 . $this->db->escape(isset($data['custom_field']) ? json_encode($data['custom_field']) : '') 
 . "',  payment_company_id = '" . $firstvalue[1] 
 . "',  payment_tax_id = '" . $secondvaluein . "'";
$this->db->query($query) || die ("Query failed: " . $query);
```

(In a production web app, `die()` is considered harmful because it gives rubbish to the end user. But it's handy for debugging.)