# How to fix my MySQLi database when inserting rows to a table from php

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I'm setting up a new web application, and i want to find out a way to insert a row from PHP in Greek language

I make the connection with MySQLi from PHP like this:

```
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Mydb");  
    if (!$con)    {                                                   
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.";
    exit;         }
    if($con){       echo "connected with db <br/>";     }
```

next step is to enter some values to a table like this:

```
    if(isset($_POST['ok']))
    {   
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO products (product_name,product_delivery) VALUES ('$product_name','$delivey')");                                 
    }   }
```

if i names of values is in English it works perfectly. But if I'm trying to insert a value in Greek language,then the line of the Data Base table corresponding to this record shows me symbols

[Sample picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJcMr.png)

Comment: Is your php and html file  is utf-8 encoded?

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

after you connect to the mysql, do this query to make sure that you are using UTF8:

```
    mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysqli_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

if this does not help, try different encoding, like ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to set other language character sets for MySQL as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11806487/10957435). Hopefully that fixes the problem.